# Does $AB = C$ together with $\deg(A),\deg(C) \leq d$ imply that $\deg(B) \leq d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, commutative-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $A,B,C \in k[x]^{n \times n}$ be polynomial square matrices with $\deg(A),\deg(C) \leq d$ where we define the degree of a matrix to be the maximum of the degrees of its entries. Moreover, assume that all involved matrices have full rank $n$ over $k(x)$ and, moreover, that $B$ is unimodular over $k[x]$, that is $\deg \det B = 0$.

> Does $AB = C$ imply $\deg(B) \leq d$ or is it possible that $B$ has degree indpendent of $d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $B$ has degree independent of $d$. For example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&-x\\ &1 & -x\\ && \ddots & \ddots\\ &&&&-x\\&&&&1}, \quad C = I,\\
B = \pmatrix{
1&x&x^2 & \cdots & x^{n-1}\\
&1&x&\ddots & \vdots\\
&&\ddots & \ddots \\
&&& 1 & x\\
&&&&1}.
$$

Comment: But here in your example $d = \deg A = n$ is the common degree bound of both $A$ and $C$ and also of $B$.

Comment: @windsheaf sorry, I missed that $\deg A$ has the same bound. In any case, I have a clever counterexample for that too

Comment: @windsheaf See my latest edit. I guess it's a very Toeplitz day today

Comment: +1 This is a great example and answer! I will accept it. Out of curiosity, do you think there are example as yours without using the dimension $n$ of the matrices? For me it looks like that if we replace '$\deg(B) \leq d$' with '$\deg(B) \leq \max\{d,n\}$', then the statement could hold true.

Comment: @windsheaf I don't think there is such an example; I think that we have something like $\deg(B) \leq nd$ in general. In the case that $C = I$, the cofactor formula for the entries of the inverse gives us an upper bound to the degree of $B$

Comment: @windsheaf Also, just a quick remark that $\deg(B) \leq \max\{d,n\}$ clearly won't hold: plugging $t^2$ in for $x$ makes $A$ into something of degree $2$ and $B$ into something of degree $2(n-1)$.

Comment: Ah true! Thank you for your kind help! :-)